# Beginner's question about function signature

Tags: haskell, types

I wrote the function `pop` as follows:

```
pop :: Int n => [a] -> n -> a
pop xs n = head $ drop n xs
```

When trying to run it, I get an error saying:

```
Expected kind '* -> Constraint', but 'Int' has kind '*'
```

However, changing the signature to

```
pop :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

Solves the issue. Why does this happen?

Comment: `Int` is not a *typeclass*, but a type, so it is `[a] -> Int -> a`.

Comment: Because one is correct syntax and one isn't? (To be more precise, `Int` is a type but not a typeclass.)  Sorry if that sounds flippant, but I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Note: it will also work if you replace `Int n` by `Int ~ n`, but that requires a language extension and is in any case completely unnecessary here - your changed signature is correct.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I think I phrased the question poorly, I wanted to understand what's the difference between those two, because in my mind they were equivalent.

Comment: @FabioLuis: the part before the `=>` are the type constraints, so the items before the `=>` should have as kind `Constraint`. `Integral a` is for example a constraint, since `Integral` is a typeclass, and there exists an `instance Integral Int` for example. But `Int` is not a typeclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably trying to generalize after seeing something like:

```
pop :: Num n => [a] -> n -> a
```

But `Int` and `Num` are very different things.  `Int` is a *type*, it has values, it goes on either side of a function arrow `->`.  `Num` is a *class* which can be thought of as a "predicate on types", and it only makes sense to use it to the left of the context "fat arrow" `=>`.  `Num n` means `n` is a numeric type.  So `Num Int` is "true", `Num Double` is "true", `Num String` is "not true".  It's not exactly like a function that can return true or false for each type, but that's one way to think about it.

(N.B. the way we usually talk about this is that there is an *instance* for `Num Int`, or `Int` is an instance of `Num`)

It's important to realize that the `n` variable here does not refer to a number but to a *type*.  The value of `n` can be `Int` or `Double` or `Rational` (or, say, `String`, but that will fail to typecheck when it doesn't satisfy the `Num` class). `pop` is polymorphic and can have a whole bunch of different signatures, depending on context.

```
pop :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
pop :: [String] -> Int -> String
pop :: [[Bool]] -> Double -> [Bool]

-- possible, but invalid because Num String is not "True"
pop :: [Int] -> String -> Int
```

See how these all match the pattern `[a] -> n -> a` for different choices of `a` and `n`?  The `Num n` constraint says that only certain choices of `n` are valid.  `a` is unconstrained, so you can choose whatever type you like.

Comment: I see, but why does ```Num n => [a] -> n -> a``` also gives me an error, this time saying ```Couldn't match expected type 'Int' with actual type 'n'```?

Comment: @FabioLuis this has to do with you usage of the variable `n` in `drop n xs`.  `drop` expects an `Int` for its first argument, but your signature says that `n` is allowed to be *any* numeric type, such as `Double`.  `drop` doesn't accept `Double`.

Answer (score 2):

`Int` is not a [*typeclass* [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_class), but a type, so it is

```
pop :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

A *typeclass* is a group of types, for example [**`Integral`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral) is a typeclass. This is a group of types that are *integral numbers*. For example `Int`, `Int32`, `Int64` and `Integer` are *members* of this typeclass. In order to be a member, one has to implement the methods the typeclass provides. For `Integral` that is for example `quot`, `rem`, etc.